# How do I get android-support-v7-appcompat to build?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I added the "android-support-v7-appcompat" library to my eclipse workspace according to the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library, but I can't get it to build...

No errors are listed under the "Problems" tab.  I have **Project > Build Automatically** checked.  I've tried cleaning the project, etc.  But nothing is ever placed into the  'bin' folder.  It just silently fails...

In my other project that reference the "android-support-v7-appcompat" project, I have the error:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   '/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/bin/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'

Any ideas why the appcompat jar file isn't being built?

Comment: `android-support-v7-appcompat` i think you access this library file from SDK folder not in your workspace, at time of import enable Copy project into workspace.

Comment: I am having same problem, did u managed to solved it on your mac?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place android-support-v7-appcompat in your work space.after that import to eclipse and add appcompat  to your project.

Answer (score 0):

delete current build try to re import from the following location

```
\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
```

Answer (score 0):

Yugesh's suggestion worked for me.  I needed to select the "**Copy project into workspace**" option when importing the project using the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res.